# Rust: Return immutable reference from mutable reference

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

I am coding in Rust for a couple of months now, but there are still things I don't understand:

```rust
// copy values from src to dest (&mut) and return immutable ref
fn copy_into<'a, T>(src: &Vec<T>, dest: &'a mut Vec<T>) -> &'a Vec<T>
where T: Clone {
    dest.clear();
    dest.extend(src.into_iter().cloned());
    dest
}

fn main() {
    let mut v1 = vec!['a', 'b', 'c'];
    let v2 = vec!['1', '2', '3'];
    let v3 = copy_into(&v2, &mut v1);
    // let v3 = &v1;  // But this line would work
    println!("{:?}", v1);
    //               ^^ immutable borrow occurs here
    println!("{:?}", v2);
    println!("{:?}", v3);
    //               --- mutable borrow later used here
}
```

Since `copy_into` returns an immutable reference, my understanding was that rust would know that we only have an immutable reference, but it seems that rust does remember the parameter `dest` and that it was a mutable reference.
In comparison, if I try to only take a reference `&v1` instead of using the function, this works.

I also tried to return `dest.as_ref()`, but I got the following error: "cannot return reference to function parameter `dest` returns a reference to data owned by the current function". This also conforts me in thinking that rust refers to `dest` and not to `v1` to know how to borrow.

This is just for learning purpose. My questions are:

- Is it correct that rust remembers the `dest` parameter and, if yes, why?
- If I did understand wrong, what is it?
- In any case, I don't get why, after the `println!` of `v1`, I cannot do the same for `v3`, `v3` is a reference to `v1`, not its content ?
- Is it possible, and how, to pass a mutable reference to a function (because I need it) and return it as an immutable one so that it behaves as if I only did `let v3 = &v1;` ?

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: `copy_into` returns a mutable reference.

Comment: Also probably relevant: [Limits of Lifetimes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/lifetime-mismatch.html).

Comment: Please prefer one main question per post, rather than four questions. In any case, this amounts to some deep misunderstandings about [mutable references](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html#mutable-references) on which it's probably worth revisiting the book section. There are also ways in which a mutable reference would implicitly convert into an immutable reference (see all [coercion sites](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/type-coercions.html#coercion-sites)), but that code does not have such a coercion site.

Comment: @isaactfa thank you for the link, this is exactly what I needed.
The code is forcing the mutable reference to live longer. It does not matter if I "just" is it as parameter or if I had declared it like `let tmp = &mut v1` and then passed it to the function.

Comment: @E_net4thecommentflagger this is one question, I could have made it less clear and hoped for some to understand my question. Also, I understand pretty well the notion of reference and mutability, what I don't get good enough is the lifetime notion in some cases like this one (which is purely theoretical)

Answer (score 0):

> Since `copy_into` returns an immutable reference

I'm not sure where you get this from, but `copy_into` returns `&'a mut Vec<T>`, which is **not** an immutable reference, it's a mutable one.

Either way, it doesn't really make a difference. The important part is that the return value carries the lifetime `'a`. The easiest way to think about lifetimes is to regard them as dependency indicators. Returning an `'a` return value means that it depends on all input values with the `'a` lifetime. That means to the compiler that as long as the return value exists, the `dest` input value is potentially still borrowed in it, and it can't be used until the return value is dropped.

> In any case, I don't get why, after the `println!` of `v1`, I cannot do the same for `v3`, `v3` is a reference to `v1`, not its content?

That's not how references work. Rust doesn't care about what exactly is happening inside of the `copy_into` function, you annotated with `'a` that the return value depends on the `dest` input value, and that's all it knows. It doesn't understand what exactly `v3` references, all it knows that it has to lock `v1` as long as `v3` exists, because that's what the lifetime annotations say.

> Is it possible, and how, to pass a mutable reference to a function (because I need it) and return it as an immutable one?

Not that I know of.

Comment: Hi, sorry, I added it by mistake but the original code wasn't returning a mutable reference.
I edited the code in my post.

Thank you for the response, and in addition with another response I understand it better.
It seems that the reference passed as parameter `&mut v1` is forced to live longer because of the assignation.
I would have expected some kind of elision but this is apparently not the case, at least not now.
Thank you

Comment: Rust isn't smart enough to understand that it is the same reference. It could be a new immutable object with interiour mutability that stores the `&mut` reference. Lifetimes aren't complex enough to contain this kind of information.